# UI Bootstrap uib-tabs panel right

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using vertical tabs in UI Bootstrap 14.3, how do you align the content to the right of the tab rather than underneath the tabs?

```
<uib-tabset vertical="true" type="pills">
    <uib-tab heading="Vertical 1">Vertical content 1</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Vertical 2">Vertical content 2</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

I have tried `class="tabs-left"` but that doesnt work.

Example [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IEMf6BDju3eUdBUqlYEV?p=preview)

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle/an example of the issue you are experiencing so we can have something to play with?

Comment: Plunker added to question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's Bootstrap. See the documentation and add the styles that do you need:

```
.nav-tabs {
  float: left;
}

.contect-tabs {
  float: left;
}
```

Example taken from de Angular UI Bootstrap: 
http://embed.plnkr.co/k0kL7AjPFfSEM8m4EG9E/